# how can a regular class have a singleton subclass in c++

Tags: c++, singleton

so i have a user class which has two subclasses: manager and regular_User and i want manager to be singleton.
can anybody help me how to do it?
thanks!

```
class user{
  public:
    //sth
  protected:
    //sth
};

class manager:public user{ //i want this to be singleton
//
};

class regular_user:public user{

};
```

Comment: By doing it the normal way with a private constructor and public static "get instance" function?

Comment: Also, if you say that `manager` inherits from `user` (if that's what you mean by "subclass") in the text, please show that in the code you post as well. Having the text and the code mismatch is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Although I question *why* you'd want `manager` to be a singleton, you could achieve something by using an *anonymous* `class` (or `struct`) with a single instance:

```
struct user {
    static struct {
    } manager;
};
```

The fun bit is allocating storage for the anonymous `struct`, since you don't know its type! You need to do this otherwise you'll get link-time errors. But C++11 has a way. Include

```
namespace {
    decltype(user::manager) user::manager;
}
```

in exactly one compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to make the class `Manager` a subclass of class `User`, you need to declare it with something like `class Manager : public User`. Then to make class `Manager` a Singleton class, you need to guarantee that only one instance of that class (one object) can be created. If you make all of its class member variables and member functions `static`, then those members will only get created once.

Comment: if manager inherits from user, then at least those members inherited from user are not static in manager